# PHP show data when get page name only on address bar clean urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

www.example.com/category/post/

my phph file

```
if($_GET['category']{
//code here;
}
```

so that was in my category file

my post file

```
if($_GET['post']{
// code here;
}
```

but when i go to that address

www.example.com/category/post/

cate
it shows me the data in category page and in post page

i want to make an if condition to category page to show data only if the address contains category and if there is nore slashes after it /post/comment/..etc so it won't show any data of the category page

I'm using htaccess for clean urls

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&&action=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&&action=$2
```

Comment: Show your .htaccess code in your question.

Comment: why not consider url rewrite?

Comment: I added my htaccess code :)

Comment: And how is this rule giving you `$_GET['category']` OR `$_GET['post']`?

Comment: as i wrote , in my index page if(isset($_GET['category'].... 

as i replace in my htaccess file page for category , and action for post :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `if($_GET['category']{` to `if($_GET['page']=='category'){`

And change `if($_GET['post']{` to `if($_GET['action']=='post'){`

Then play with conditions as you want.

**UPD** For your comment

Write conditions like this

```
if(@$_GET['action']!=''){
    if($_GET['action']=='post'){
    //some code for post
    }
}
else if(@$_GET['page']=='category'){
//some code for category
}
```

For different files

```
if(@$_GET['action']=='' && $_GET['page']=='category'){
//some code for category
}
```

Comment: I already tried this , but the problem when i go to my post page , i get all the content of my category as it is requested in my url . I want to show category data only if there is nothing after it

Comment: @Hasan Zohdy I don't know how update works in stackoverflow, so type here too, that I update answer.

Comment: Try change `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&&action=$2` to `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2`. Delete second rule string. Try change by copy not typing.